# Execute background process from django that can't be interrupted by the web server

Tags: python, django, linux, apache, background

I'm seeing all kinds of threads like this and they have accepted answers, and yet I'm still stuck on this.

I have a view that should start a backup procedure, and I got it to the point where the view returns, and the process is still running in the background, however **if apache is restarted**, the backup process then dies.

```
def partStartJob(request):
    import subprocess
    p=subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/nohup','/usr/bin/python', '/(somewhere)/scripts/backup/testbackup.py'] )
    # FIXME: This process dies when apache restarts.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe less elegant, but definitely most simple, I scheduled my process for "now" with the **at** command.  Done.

```
os.system("echo '/usr/bin/python /(somewhere)/scripts/backup/testbackup.py' | at now")
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to use a completely separate process for the backup. The best way to do this is to use a message queue - the view puts the backup request on the queue, and a separate listener picks it up and runs the backup, independently of Apache.

[Celery](http://ask.github.com/celery/) is a distributed task manager that deals with all this for you, although it would be fairly easy to roll your own with RabbitMQ and the Python AMQP library.

Comment: I do appreciate that, but it just doesn't fit.  I don't want to install a library to accomplish what I know my system must be able to do.

Comment: Your system can do it, but it can't, say, check on the result of the operation, ensure that eventually the operation succeeds, or any of the other things you want with a task like this. Yes, you have to install some extra libraries, but compared to Django itself, celery + rabbitMQ are trivialities.